# Offspring generating function in Branching process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions, branching-rules

> Find the extinction probability for a branching process with offspring
>   distribution $a =(1∕6, 1∕2, 1∕3)$.
>
> **Solution**
>
> The mean of the offspring distribution is
>   $\mu = 0(1∕6)+ 1(1∕2)+ 2(1∕3)= 7∕6 > 1$,
>   so this is the supercritical case.
>
> The offspring generating function is
>   $G(s)= 1/6 + s/2 + s^2/3$.
>
> Solving $s = G(s)= 1/6 + s/2 + s^2/3$ gives the quadratic equation $s^2∕3 − s∕2 + 1∕6 = 0$, with roots $s = 1$ and $s = 1∕2$.
>
> The smallest positive root is the probability of eventual extinction $e = 1∕2$.

I have several questions.

1. What would be the offspring generating function in critical and sub-critical cases?
2. Why is $s = G(s)$?

Comment: What do you know about Branching processes? The second property is a basic theorem on extinction probability. The generating function of a critical or sub-critical BP depends on the offsping distribution , so what type of answer can be given to 1)?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, *The generating function of a critical or sub-critical BP depends on the offspring distribution* - I want to see what would PGF look like in each of those cases.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, *The second property is a basic theorem on extinction probability.* - kindly, supply me some material to study.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, *What do you know about Branching processes?* - I just started it today.